# iCloud: Getting an array of txt files present in the cloud on OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, icloud, nsmetadataquery

I am trying to get an array of txt files in my app's iCloud folder using a NSMetadataQuery as recommended by Apple:

```
NSMetadataQuery *query = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
[query setSearchScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope]]; 

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K ENDSWITH '.txt'", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey];
[query setPredicate:pred];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(queryDidFinishGathering:) name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification object:query];

[query startQuery];
```

Unfortunately queryDidFinishGathering: never gets called. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using ARC, which means that you need to retain a strong reference to objects that you allocate or they will go away.

You are calling `alloc` on your `query` object, which under manual retain/release would mean that the `query` object would remain alive until you send it a `release` or `autorelease` message.

However, under ARC, the compiler inserts those calls for you and because it doesn't know that you want the `query` object to stick around, it releases the `query` object after you call `[query startQuery]`. Because the object has been released, it never posts the notification.

You should instead hold a strong reference to the `query` object. The most straightforward way to do this is to make it an instance variable, or a `strong` property.

```
@interface YourObject : NSObject
{
    NSMetadataQuery *query;
}
@end
```

or

```
@interface YourObject : NSObject{}
@property (strong) NSMetadataQuery *query;
@end
```